# How to configure a Jenkins node in a restricted environment using SSH?

Tags: unix, jenkins, ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

The Jenkins master and one of the deployment server are in two different network. We want to setup a node/slave agent on the deployment server. The only way to access to deployment server is though a Jump host which has access to both networks. Is there a way to setup SSH slave on the deployment server from Jenkins master through the jump host?